# Adding java object to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

When i execute this snippet, i expect to have:

- row(0) = (paul,30)
- row(1) = (john,20)

But i don't get why instead i get: row(0) = (john,20) and row(1) = (john,20)

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Classname> yourList = new ArrayList<Classname>();

    Classname cl = new Classname();

    cl.Name="paul";
    cl.Age=30;
    yourList.add(cl);

    cl.Name="john";
    cl.Age=20;
    yourList.add(cl);

    System.out.println("List row 0 = "+yourList.get(0).Name+" - "+yourList.get(0).Age);
    System.out.println("List row 1 = "+yourList.get(1).Name+" - "+yourList.get(1).Age);
}
class Classname{

    public String Name;
    public Integer Age;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because if you `add(...)` something to a `List`, you add a *reference* to the object to the list, not a clone of the object. Thus, if you change the classes name (`cl.Name="john", attributes should be written in camelCase btw), you also change the object that is referenced by the list. You can avoid this by writing `cl = new Classname()` after you have added the first class to your `List` (i.e. after `yourList.add(c1);`). And one minor note: do not write `cl`. This can be easily misread as `c1` (c-one).

Comment: To avoid that, make a new clasname object and add it then to the list.

Answer (score 3):

You created one object of Classname and then cl has reference to this object. For each object you have to create its own reference:

```
Classname cl1 = new Classname();

cl1.Name="paul";
cl1.Age=30;
yourList.add(cl1);

Classname cl2 = new Classname();
cl2.Name="john";
cl2.Age=20;
yourList.add(cl2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a difference between:

```
Classname cl = new Classname();

cl.Name="paul";
cl.Age=30;
yourList.add(cl);

cl.Name="john";
cl.Age=20;
yourList.add(cl);
```

and:

```
Classname cl1 = new Classname();
Classname cl2 = new Classname();

cl1.Name="paul";
cl1.Age=30;
yourList.add(cl1);

cl2.Name="john";
cl2.Age=20;
yourList.add(cl2);
```

The first version creates **just one object**. Then you add a *reference* to that object to your `ArrayList`. Then you modify the same object, giving it a new `Name` and `Age`. It *does affect* its representation in the list, since you did not add any copies of the object to the list - you added a reference.

The second version creates two, independent objects with different properties and places their references into the list, which results in the behaviour you are seeking